# How to parse possibly missing unsigned integers with boost::spirit?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I need to parse two unsigned integers separated by white spaces into two std::optionals. One or both could be nans. For example valid inputs: "123 456" or "123 nan" or "nan 456" or "nan nan". What would be the most elegant rule for this? Thanks!

Comment: It's customary to show what you've tried. For example in this case it would tell us whether you are using Spirit Qi or Spirit X3, or the target datastructure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming some things like,

- an attribute type like

  ```
  using Pair = std::pair<std::optional<int>, std::optional<int>>;
  ```
- using Spirit Qi
- not desiring case-insensitivity
- requiring full input to be consumed
- requiring two tokens in the input always, with space only required when ambiguous (e.g. `1nan` is fine without whitespace)

I'd suggest something like

```
auto optint = qi::copy(qi::int_ | "nan");
qi::rule<It, Pair()> p = qi::skip(qi::space) [ optint >> optint ];
```

### Demo

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c9893814686e78d)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <optional>
#include <iomanip>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

using Pair = std::pair<std::optional<int>, std::optional<int>>;
using It   = std::string::const_iterator;

template <typename T> std::string display(std::optional<T> const& v) {
    return v? std::to_string(v.value()) : "nullopt";
}

static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Pair const& pair) {
    return os << "(" << display(pair.first) << ", " << display(pair.second) << ")";
}

int main() {
    auto optint = qi::copy(qi::int_ | "nan");
    qi::rule<It, Pair()> p = qi::skip(qi::space) [ optint >> optint ];

    for (std::string const input : {"123 456", "123 nan", "nan 456", "nan nan"}) {
        Pair parsed;
        if (parse(begin(input), end(input), p >> qi::eoi, parsed)) {
            std::cout << quoted(input) << " -> " << parsed << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << quoted(input) << " -> Did not parse" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Printing

```
"123 456" -> (123, 456)
"123 nan" -> (123, nullopt)
"nan 456" -> (nullopt, 456)
"nan nan" -> (nullopt, nullopt)
```

### BONUS

The same program in X3: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92fb99cff768bb6f, printing

```
"123 456" -> (123, 456)
"123 nan" -> (123, nullopt)
"nan 456" -> (nullopt, 456)
"nan nan" -> (nullopt, nullopt)
"123nan" -> (123, nullopt)
"nan456" -> (nullopt, 456)
```

Requiring at least a single separating whitespace: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1430e6be4727bff2, printing

```
"123 456" -> (123, 456)
"123 nan" -> (123, nullopt)
"nan 456" -> (nullopt, 456)
"nan nan" -> (nullopt, nullopt)
"123nan" -> Did not parse
"nan456" -> Did not parse
```